# Click event on iframe doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an I frame and I need to get the x and y coordinates if the user click on the iframe. If I use this code in the controller:

```
 $('iframe').attr("src","JavaScript:'iframe content test'");
```

The everything works OK. But when I use this code in the html the alert doesn't show

```
<iframe id="iframe" ng-src="{{pdfFile}}" style="width:100%; height:800px; margin-top:20px;"></iframe>
```

The rest of the code:

```
 $('iframe').load(function () {
    $(this).contents().find("body").on('click', function (event)
    {
        console.log(event);
        alert('test ' + event.clientX + " -- " + event.clientY);
    });
});
```

Comment: Since the iframe body is in another DOM, I don't think it will work.

Comment: Thank you.What do I need to change to make it work. if I change the code like: <iframe style="width:100%; height:800px; margin-top:20px;" src="{{pdfFile}}"></iframe>. Works only if there is no pdf file loaded

Comment: pdf isn't an html file.

Comment: A PDF won't have a DOM, but I suspect it would be a security vulnerability to let a parent iframe query the DOM of a child iframe. Clever things can be done with `postMessage()` though.

Comment: @charlietfl if you have an answer, please share it.

Comment: You have oversimplified how pdf's get handled in browser

Comment: Thank you. Can somebody point me to the right direction please.